# How to find a certain pattern using regular expressions in vb.net

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm completely new VB.net regular expressions, however I know Perl regex pretty well, but when I tried to use perl regex type find and replaces it doesn't work. I'm trying to replace all

> "figure digit", "section digit", "table digit" expressions with ignorecase

which in perl is like

```
Find "figure (\d+)"
Replace "<a href="fig$1">figure $1</href>"
Find "table (\d+)"
Replace "<a href="tab$1">table $1</href>" and so on
```

How do I achieve this in vb.net

Comment: I don't understand your goal, with "figure (\d+)" Replace "figure $1" you replace your match group by your match group so there is no effect, nop ?

Comment: now do you understand? check the edited question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of using [Regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx) in VB.Net

```
' Top of the file

Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

' Inside a method (for example)

' declares and initialize a regex object
Dim regexObj As New Regex("(figure|section|table) (\d+)", RegexOptions.Compiled Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
' Compiled option is strictly needed here (good when reusing same regex)

' some sample text
Dim input = "some text with a figure 10 or a section 20 or a table 30"

Dim output = regexObj.Replace(input, "[$1] ($2)")
' output will be
' "some text with a [figure] (10) or a [section] (20) or a [table] (30)"
```